# Python/Numpy: problems with type conversion in vectorize and item

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

I am writing a function to extract values from datetimes over arrays.  I want the function to operate on a Pandas DataFrame or a numpy ndarray.

The values should be returned in the same way as the Python datetime properties, e.g.

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime(2016, 10, 12, 13)
dt.year
  => 2016
dt.second
  => 0
```

For a DataFrame this is reasonably easy to handle using `applymap()` (although there may well be a better way).  I tried the same approach for numpy ndarrays using `vectorize()`, and I'm running into problems.  Instead of the values I was expecting, I end up with very large integers, sometimes negative.

This was pretty baffling at first, but I figured out what is happening: the vectorized function is using `item` instead of `__get__` to get the values out of the ndarray.  This seems to automatically convert each `datetime64` object to a `long`:

```
nd[1][0]
  => numpy.datetime64('1986-01-15T12:00:00.000000000')
nd[1].item()
  => 506174400000000000L
```

The long seems to be the number of nanoseconds since epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00).  Somewhere along the line the values are converted to integers and they overflow, hence the negative numbers.

So that's the problem.  Please can someone help me fix it?  The only thing I can think of is doing the conversion manually, but this would effectively mean reimplementing a chunk of the `datetime` module.

Is there some alternative to `vectorize` that doesn't use `item()`?

Thanks!

Minimal code example:

```
## DataFrame works fine
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'dts': [datetime(1970, 1, 1, 1), datetime(1986, 1, 15, 12),
                         datetime(2016, 7, 15, 23)]})
exp = pd.DataFrame({'dts': [1, 15, 15]})

df_func = lambda x: x.day    
out = df.applymap(df_func)

assert out.equals(exp)

## numpy ndarray is more difficult
from numpy import datetime64 as dt64, timedelta64 as td64, vectorize  # for brevity

# The unary function is a little more complex, especially for days and months where the minimum value is 1
nd_func = lambda x: int((dt64(x, 'D') - dt64(x, 'M') + td64(1, 'D')) / td64(1, 'D'))

nd = df.as_matrix()
exp = exp.as_matrix()
  => array([[ 1],
            [15],
            [15]])

# The function works as expected on a single element...
assert nd_func(nd[1][0]) == 15

# ...but not on an ndarray
nd_vect = vectorize(nd_func)
out = nd_vect(nd)
  => array([[    -105972749999999],
            [ 3546551532709551616],
            [-6338201187830896640]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Py3 the error is `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long`.

```
In [215]: f=np.vectorize(nd_func,otypes=[int])
In [216]: f(dts)
... 
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

but if I change the datetime units, it runs ok

```
In [217]: f(dts.astype('datetime64[ms]'))
Out[217]: array([ 1, 15, 15])
```

We could dig into this in more depth, but this seems to be simplest solution.

Keep in mind that `vectorize` is a convenience function; it makes iterating over multidimensions easier. But for a 1d array it is basically

```
np.array([nd_func(i) for i in dts])
```

But note that we don't have to use iteration:

```
In [227]: (dts.astype('datetime64[D]') - dts.astype('datetime64[M]') + td64(1,'D')) / td64(1,'D').astype(int)
Out[227]: array([ 1, 15, 15], dtype='timedelta64[D]')
```

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, you make an excellent point about there being no need for vectorize – using `astype('datetime64[$UNIT]')` (hopefully you can see through my horribly mixed syntax there) on the whole array works a treat